# Implement D3 Interactive and dynamically rendered line charts to Vue.js app

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, vuejs2

I just finished the d3 party of my app and now I want to implement it into a Vue.js app. Now I headed to the problem Vue does not like D3 to change things in the DOM.

Here is the code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3kg75tx/)

I think Vue has a problem with `.select("#" + name)`

**Important to know** is; My `div`'s are getting created dynamically depending on the amount of data the component is getting. In the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/p3kg75tx/) there are three charts but it can be more or less. When you look at the code you can see that its written to work with dynamic data. If you need the play D3 code just let me know.

How can i get this working together?

Comment: Have you ever gotten this error in the fiddle? Can you provide steps to reproduce the error?

Comment: I think this is more of a vue thing. Vue dont want other library to make changes to the DOM. Is there any way to get around D3 manipulating the DOM?